# Simple connection to mongodb in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have created simple react app using 'create-react-app'. This app contains form, validation and bootstrap things. Nothing fancy yet works like a charm.

I have also signed up to mongo to get a free cluster so I can send over some data to. So I have this URL:

```
mongodb+srv://matt:passwprd@cluster0-jlasm.mongodb.net/test
```

Now, all I want to do is to send JSON data from the form to mongo but I don't know how.

When I am following tutorials and installing MongoDB, mongoose or whatever packages and adding basic setup for future CRUD operations:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb+srv://mattOsuch:brainhub123@cluster0-jlasm.mongodb.net/test';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  db.close();
});
```

The entire application crashes:

```
./node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'C:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\brainhub\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib'
```

I used to send data using jQuery or mysql_query in PHP but I can't overcome this problem. In other words I want to achieve functionality like presented in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jsqz5op4fH8 So as I said, simple data update.

My suspicion is that react-scripts server listener has some sort of conflict with mongo but I am not sure.

Please help me because I am loosing my nerves.

Comment: Generally speaking you would want to build such functionality (database CRUD) on the server-side, whereas your react app is running on the client side. What you're doing is **not secure** because you're hardcoding the database credentials into your client-side application, which any visitor can view the source of.

Comment: good comment @niels +

Comment: @NielsdeBruin, so what is the correct approach of developing that? I need at least some sort of tips because I am running out of ideas.

Comment: @MateuszOsuch This shouldn't be done in React. You need a separate server side app/ API to do that. React would call that API.

Comment: If your react app is the dashboard inside a car, you're asking me how to build an engine.. There's a plethora of options for building a backend, but since you're already working in Javascript you could search for tutorials on how to build a Node.js application with Mongoose. It could either render React views for you or you'd need to build an API. Either way this is a whole different story than simply writing a React app, however it is the correct approach.

Comment: @BrahmaDev, any links, tutorials of how can I build sever side API for my project?

Comment: @MateuszOsuch There are a lot of server-side platforms or frameworks such as Node.js, Laravel, Dot NET Core and more. Each one of these as its own language: Javascript, PHP, and C# respectively, so you should learn the language first and then decide which platform/framework to use and also, learn topics like HTTP (protocol), Template Engines (if you do server-side rendering) and many more. So, it's not such an easy thing to learn server side, I recommend you to start now!

Comment: Hi did u figure it out?

Comment: @NielsdeBruin What if I only want to run the app locally? How would I then connect to MongoDB on the client-side using React?

Comment: @pfincent Then it's as simple as installing MongoDB on your computer, create a database and connect it to your backend. 
Remember, React is a front-end and for security reasons, it is advised to connect the database to a backend then pass the data to your front-end.

Answer (score 1):

You are using node.js so start server app try using express routing here is a link to a tutorial https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb or https://codeburst.io/hitchhikers-guide-to-back-end-development-with-examples-3f97c70e0073 or try doing a google search(node.js mongodb and express).

Then when returning a request from server send the data required then use your react client to handle the data recived

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works!

```
handleSubmit(){
let databody = {
    "name": this.state.name,
     // Remaining form Data
}

return fetch('mongodb+srv://mattOsuch:brainhub123@cluster0-jlasm.mongodb.net/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(databody),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data)); 
}

render(){
return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
               // Form Fields
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form> 
    </div>
);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To connect to MongoDb in javascript, you must use a node.js server.
It is therefore impossible to directly connect your React application to your MongoDb cluster.

For more information, visit the official [MongoDb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/quick-start/)

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to create a React.js on the frontend and then node.js on the backend web application.
2. Then, you need to connect your mongodb collection to your Node.js server.
3. Then you can send your form data to your node.js server and your node.js server will send your form data to your mongodb collection.

Making a full-stack React-NodeJS-MongoDB web application can be a little challenging, if you do not know NodeJS. So you might first start with EJS-NodeJS-MongoDB  web application. But in any case, here are links for your question:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3isCTSUdXaQ&t=2248s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oa0pMn0tvU4&t=1316s